# Our community in one brief sentence

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes, elevator-pitch, tagline

From [the SO/SE blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/):

> Instead of stressing out over the vagaries of the brutal, cut-throat .com domain market and debating the “least worst” domain name options ad nauseam, simply focus on telling the world what your community is about. Don’t even think about the domain name! Give us the one sentence “elevator pitch” for your community. How would you explain your site to a stranger you met on an elevator? It’s about … what, exactly?
>
> [...]
>
> For the forseeable future, don’t even attempt to “Pick a domain name!”. If you ask the wrong question, you’ll just get endless variations of wrong answers. The correct question, the one we should have been asking the community all along, is this:
>
> Tell us what your community is about in one brief sentence!

(With thanks to Isaac at [meta.Mathematics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/898/tell-us-what-your-community-is-about-in-one-brief-sentence).)

Comment: Wait, which is the real discussion here? @Robert Cartaino already started the elevator-pitch/tagline discussion at [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/405/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline).

Answer (score 5):

I believe this community is about providing Quality answers and questions to all issues pertaining to Ubuntu and the Ubuntu family. Something like "*Quality answers for human beings*" comes to mind when thinking in short what we aim to do here. In addition to quality (which I believe goes hand-in-hand with Quality) is Authoritative.

So more along the lines of:

"This site's aim is to provide Correct and concise answers of the highest quality for users of Ubuntu - and it's derivatives."

Comment: +1 Pretty close to what I would have said.

Comment: Agreed.  My hope is that we leverage the tools that Stack Exchange provides to attract high-quality answers to questions.  We'll lose if you Google for "Ubuntu broadcom wireless not working" and all you get back are a bunch of terse posts about editing commands in the terminal.  The Ubuntu community would benefit from answers that have screenshot walkthroughs and well thought out explanations.

Answer (score 4):

The [Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct) has some basic tenets in it. However the [governance page](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/governance) has a nice quote:

```
 We aim to make Ubuntu a wonderful place to participate.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since working with ubuntu involves facing issues and troubleshooting along with imagining some ideas and realizing them, I feel the focus of this site is to solve problems and realize the solutions to our idea of how the computer should be used. So a brief 1-liner about what our community is about would be ...

Helping people solve problems and build their ideal desktop with Ubuntu and its derivatives.