# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion, elevator-pitch, tagline

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: There is also this related thread: http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/372/tell-us-what-your-community-is-about-in-one-brief-sentence

Comment: Ya, this is a duplicate, I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't believe so - simply because one is "What is this community about" while this is just a tag line.

Comment: That other question seems different to me.

Answer (score 5):

A short elevator pitch/tagline:

> [AskUbuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) : Learn by asking. Learn by example.

Answer (score 4):

> Ask Ubuntu: because we're not the Ubuntu Forums

Answer (score 1):

> [AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/): Improving the Ubuntu experience; one answer at a time.

Answer (score 0):

> [AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/): Because between us: we know everything

Answer (score 0):

> Ask Ubuntu: Learn by asking. Lead by example.

A slight modification of Stefan's

Answer (score -1):

> [AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/): [How about a screenshot with that?](http://www.usatoday.com/money/economy/2009-04-09-upsell-extra-sales_N.htm)

Answer (score -1):

AskUbuntu.com: Finally, Linux Just Works.

Answer (score -2):

My 2c

```
Ask your way to ubuntu uber-geekiness !
```

;-)